# Compute the missing angle!

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

So, the question itself is pretty straight forward. Given a convex quadrilateral, compute the missing angle.

Now, full disclosure, I have solved the problem and verified the answer to be 92. I am posting this here since I am curious if there are more efficient solutions.

[image]

Comment: Please edit to include your solution.

Comment: I mean, I don't mind, but is it necessary?

Comment: @RyugaKishatu: We can't tell what counts as a "more efficient solution" until we've seen yours. Also, seeing what you've done helps us avoid wasting time explaining things you already understand. Plus, it's annoying to expend effort devising, composing, and illustrating a solution only to have the asker say, "Yeah, that's how I did it. I was looking for something else."

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I'll put mine up then. I'm less than half an hour old on this website so forgive me if I'm not totally up to speed.

Comment: Context is essential ! The below answers should not have been given. You say you solved the problem , so show how and then (and only then!) we can find out whether it can be improved. We are no clairvoyants !

Comment: I did post my own answer here, please take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another way of solving this problem (may or may not be more efficient depending on knowledge and experience).

[image]

Let $E$ be the intersection of the line $BD$ with the circumcircle of $ABC$.

$\angle AEB = \angle ACB = \angle BAC = \angle BEC = 20^\circ \\
\Rightarrow EB \text{ is the angle bisector of } \angle AEC \\
\quad \\
\text{Since } D \text{ lies on } EB \text{, and} \\
\angle ADC = 110^\circ = 90^\circ + \dfrac{40^\circ}{2} = 90^\circ + \dfrac{\angle AEC}{2} \\
D \text{ is the incentre of } \triangle AEC. \qquad(\text{This is a well-known lemma, comment if you need its proof}) \\
\quad\\
\Rightarrow DA \text{ is the bisector of } \angle EAC \text{, which is equal to } \angle EBC \\
\Rightarrow \angle EBC = \angle EAC = 2\angle DAC = 92^\circ$

Comment: Really awesome approach using the incenter lemma! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since I was asked to post my own solution, here it is. Forgive my heavenly handwriting and drawing, I'm just way too good at it /s

Here's my solution:

[image]

For those wondering how I concluded the cyclic quadrilateral:

We extend BE from point B such that AB=BC=BE. We then join C and E, forming an isosceles triangle CBE where <CBE=40 and the base angles are 70 each. Notice that <CEA and <ADC are 70 and 110 respectively. Also notice that <DAE and <DCE are 66 and 114 respectively. Since the opposite angles add up 180, we can conclude that Quadrilateral DCEA is in fact cyclic.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If only I knew what that actually means 

Comment: If you follow the link, you'll see what MathJax syntax looks like. Basically, type your proof in the text, and wrap things in dollar signs to make them format more nicely, e.g. \angle ABC becomes $\angle ABC$.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep this in mind!

Comment: How did you determine that $DCEA$ is cyclic?

Comment: We extend BE from point B such that AB=BC=BE. We then join C and E, forming an isosceles triangle CBE where <CBE=40 and the base angles are 70 each. Notice that <CEA and <ADC are 70 and 110 respectively. Also notice that <DAE and <DCE are 66 and 114 respectively. Since the opposite angles add up 180, we can conclude that Quadrilateral DCEA is in fact cyclic. Hope this helped!

Comment: @RyugaKishatu: Please add any context or clarifications to the body of the answer. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.

Comment: Done. Hopefully the edition makes my approach as clear as possible.